# discord py Remove all individual roles

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to take away all the roles that the person has on that server by typing a command and mentioning a bot person.

I think it should be used for

Comment: Next time, please try to attempt coding a solution. Then if you have issues, you can post the code with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the `member.remove_roles()` function.

E.g.

```
await member.remove_roles(*member.roles[1:])
```

`[1:]` is used to prevent an error, as the first role in every `roles` array is the default '@everyone' role.

Reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Member.roles

Comment: i,m a error 
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'